# Can't load truncated images keras generator in r

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network

Getting the error below trying to train the output layers of a model that uses inceptionV3.
Flow_from_directory generator works fine but when i try and train the model (weights are freezer, only training final layers) this error pops up:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
>   StopIteration: image file is truncated (49 bytes not processed)

In Python i know how to solve the problem, just use the code below:

```
from PIL import Image
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

What about in R?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
library(reticulate)

PIL <- import("PIL")

PIL$ImageFile$LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES <- TRUE
```

quote from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/438)